# Monitor ViewHolder cached in RecyclerView

Tags: android, caching

As I understand, RecyclerView cached a list of ViewHolder for reuse. Is there a way to monitor and observe the cached ViewHolder in run time such as how many ViewHolder currently are cached and the detail properties of itemView. I am trying to debug some memory leak issue.

Comment: `RecyclerView.Recycler` ?

Comment: Correct. It is what I am looking for. Thanks @psking